# How to securely stream audio file using html audio element

Tags: angular, cookies, .net-core, jwt, html5-audio

I have .net core backend which have REST api endpoint for downloading uploaded mp3 files. I like audio elements feature when it start to playing as soon as it get enough data so I don't want to download whole file separately. My front is done with Angular 5. My other API endpoint uses JWT token authentication because I can set manually JWT to Header but when I'm using audio-element, audio element itself make API call and I cannot add Header to request.

```
<audio height="40" id="audio1" preload="auto" style="visibility: hidden" type="audio/mpeg" src="api/audio/2269" >
</audio>
```

This works well when I use cookie authentication when I'm serving my frontend from same origin where my REST API is. But now I'm planning to move frontend to other cloud and then I realized that somehow cookies are working on same domain only. I check that I don't even get cookie from different domain to my browser.

So my question is can I authenticate user somehow with JWT token when using html audio element? 
Or can I configure cookie authentication in .net Core 2 somehow to allow different domains. I found this Cookie.Domain [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x) but I'm not sure does it work with this.

Here is my current cookie configuration in .net core.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => 
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "access_token";
                options.LoginPath = "/login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/login";
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options => 
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my problem and it was Azure's CORS settings what was messing my CORS settings in .net core. I removed them in Azure and then I get my .net core CORS settings correct. Here is my second question: [How to configure .net core to send authentication cookies to different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218862/how-to-configure-net-core-to-send-authentication-cookies-to-different-domain/49242687#49242687)